# selected value for @Html.DropDownListFor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Selected drowdown value is not getting displayed

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AgeGroup, ViewBag.AgeGroup as SelectList, "Please select", new {@class = "form-control", id = "ddl_InvAgeGroup", name = "AgeGroup"} )
```

Comment: The format is `@Html.DropDownList(m => m.yourProperty, Model.YourSelectList, "Please select", new { ... }` - you need a property to bind to and a property for the `SelectList` and if the value of the property matchs the value of one of the options it will be selected

Comment: I modified my code but also it is not dispalying selected value and instead of that in drop down it is showing 2 times dropdown values

Comment: You seem to be using the same property for the collection and the selected value: `AgeGroup`. That's not how this helper is supposed to be used. You need 2 properties on your view model: one scalar type that will hold the selected value and one IEnumerable property that will hold the list of possible values to display in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect you could have 2 properties on your view model: one that will hold the selected value and one that will hold the list of possible values:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string AgeGroup { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AgeGroups { get; set; }
}
```

that you would populate in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();

    // Obviously the list of possible values might be 
    // coming from a database or something else
    model.AgeGroups = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "group 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "group 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "group 3" },
    };

    // an element with Value="2" from the previous collection will be selected
    model.AgeGroup = "2";

    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.AgeGroup, 
    Model.AgeGroups, 
    "Please select", 
    new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddl_InvAgeGroup", name = "AgeGroup" }
)
```

Comment: but i need dynamic data

Comment: Sure, just project your dynamic data into the `AgeGroups` collection property of your view model, the same way you populated your `ViewBag.AgeGroup`.